# How to parse a RFC 2822 date/time into a Python datetime?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, time, python-2.5

I have a date of the form specified by RFC 2822 -- say `Fri, 15 May 2009 17:58:28 +0000`, as a string. Is there a quick and/or standard way to get it as a `datetime` object in Python 2.5? I tried to produce a strptime format string, but the +0000 timezone specifier confuses the parser.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that parsedate will ignore the offset.

Do this instead:

```
from email.utils import parsedate_tz
print parsedate_tz('Fri, 15 May 2009 17:58:28 +0700')
```

Comment: Encountered the issue and found out that, starting with python 3.3, `email.utils` has a new function called [`parsedate_to_datetime`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime) that outputs a `datetime` instance directly.

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to elaborate on previous answers. `email.utils.parsedate` and `email.utils.parsedate_tz` both return tuples, since the OP needs a `datetime.datetime` object, I'm adding these examples for completeness:

```
from email.utils import parsedate
from datetime import datetime
import time

t = parsedate('Sun, 14 Jul 2013 20:14:30 -0000')
d1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(t))
```

Or:

```
d2 = datetime.datetime(*t[:6])
```

Note that `d1` and `d2` are both naive datetime objects, there's no timezone information stored. If you need aware datetime objects, check the `tzinfo` `datetime()` arg.

Alternatively you could use the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) module

Answer (score 12):

```
from email.utils import parsedate
print parsedate('Fri, 15 May 2009 17:58:28 +0000')
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate).

Answer (score 10):

It looks like Python 3.3 going forward has a new method `parsedate_to_datetime` in email.utils that takes care of the intermediate steps:

> **email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(date)**
>
> The inverse of format_datetime(). Performs the same function as parsedate(), but on
> success returns a datetime. If the input date has a timezone of -0000,
> the datetime will be a naive datetime, and if the date is conforming
> to the RFCs it will represent a time in UTC but with no indication of
> the actual source timezone of the message the date comes from. If the
> input date has any other valid timezone offset, the datetime will be
> an aware datetime with the corresponding a timezone tzinfo.
>
> New in version 3.3.

http://python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime

Answer (score 8):

There is a parsedate function in [email.util](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html).
It parses all valid RFC 2822 dates and some special cases.

Answer (score 8):

[`email.utils.parsedate_tz(date)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz) is the function to use. Following are some variations.

## Email date/time string ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55)) to unix timestamp in float seconds:

```py
import email.utils
import calendar
def email_time_to_timestamp(s):
    tt = email.utils.parsedate_tz(s)
    if tt is None: return None
    return calendar.timegm(tt) - tt[9]

import time
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime(email_time_to_timestamp("Wed, 04 Jan 2017 09:55:45 -0800"))))
# 2017-01-04T17:55:45Z
```

Make sure you **do not use** [`mktime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime) (which interprets the time_struct in your computer’s local time, not UTC); use [`timegm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) or [`mktime_tz`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.mktime_tz) instead (but beware caveat for `mktime_tz` in the next paragraph).

If you are sure that you have python version 2.7.4, 3.2.4, 3.3, or newer, then you can use [`email.utils.mktime_tz(tt)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.mktime_tz) instead of `calendar.timegm(tt) - tt[9]`. Before that, `mktime_tz` gave incorrect times when invoked during the local time zone’s fall daylight savings transition ([bug 14653](http://bugs.python.org/issue14653)).

Thanks to @j-f-sebastian for [caveats about mktime and mktime_tz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790795/parsing-date-with-timezone-from-an-email#comment35349147_1790885).

## Email date/time string ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55)) to “aware” `datetime` on python 3.3:

On python 3.3 and above, use [`email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime), which returns an aware `datetime` with the original zone offset:

```py
import email.utils
email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime(s)

print(email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime("Wed, 04 Jan 2017 09:55:45 -0800").isoformat())
# 2017-01-04T09:55:45-08:00
```

Caveat: this will throw `ValueError` if the time falls on a leap second e.g. `email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime("Sat, 31 Dec 2016 15:59:60 -0800")`.

## Email date/time string ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55)) to “aware” `datetime` in UTC zone:

This just converts to timestamp and then to UTC `datetime`:

```py
import email.utils
import calendar
import datetime
def email_time_to_utc_datetime(s):
    tt = email.utils.parsedate_tz(s)
    if tt is None: return None
    timestamp = calendar.timegm(tt) - tt[9]
    return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(email_time_to_utc_datetime("Wed, 04 Jan 2017 09:55:45 -0800").isoformat())
# 2017-01-04T17:55:45
```

## Email date/time string ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3), [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#page-55)) to python “aware” `datetime` with original offset:

Prior to python 3.2, python did not come with tzinfo implementations, so here an example using [`dateutil.tz.tzoffset`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzoffset) (`pip install dateutil`):

```py
import email.utils
import datetime
import dateutil.tz
def email_time_to_datetime(s):
    tt = email.utils.parsedate_tz(s)
    if tt is None: return None
    tz = dateutil.tz.tzoffset("UTC%+02d%02d"%(tt[9]//60//60, tt[9]//60%60), tt[9])
    return datetime.datetime(*tt[:5]+(min(tt[5], 59),), tzinfo=tz)

print(email_time_to_datetime("Wed, 04 Jan 2017 09:55:45 -0800").isoformat())
# 2017-01-04T09:55:45-08:00
```

If you are using python 3.2, you can use the builtin `tzinfo` implementation [`datetime.timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone): `tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=tt[9]))` instead of the third-party [`dateutil.tz.tzoffset`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzoffset).

Thanks to @j-f-sebastian again [for note on clamping the leap second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object#comment44370541_1697838).