# How do you convert a time.struct_time object into a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime

How do you convert a Python `time.struct_time` object into a `datetime.datetime` object?

I have a library that provides the first one and a second library that wants the second one.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

Use [time.mktime()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) to convert the time tuple (in localtime) into seconds since the Epoch, then use [datetime.fromtimestamp()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) to get the datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(struct))
```

Comment: Note that this fails before 1900. You modern people never remember this limitation!

Comment: will this lose the `tm_isdst` data? I think so, the resulting datetime object remains naive to the extent to return `None` on `.dst()` even if `struct.tm_isdst` is `1`.

Comment: This will usually work. However, it will fail if the time tuple is beyond the values mktime accepts, for example for the value (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1). I have encountered this after parsing the Date header on an HTTP request which returned this tuple.

Comment: As @naxa hints, this will give you a datetime with DST correction, even if the original had no DST offset.

Comment: @richvdh:  C standard specifies that `mktime()` should take `tm_isdst` into account and Python `time.mktime()` calls C `mktime()` function on CPython. `mktime()` may choose the wrong local time  when it is ambiguous (e.g., during end-of-DST ("fall back") transition) if `struct.tm_isdst` is `-1` or if `mktime()` on the given platform ignores the *input* `tm_isdst`. Also, if the local timezone had different utc offset in the past and C `mktime()` does not use a historical tz database that can provide the old utc offset values then `mktime()` may return a wrong (e.g., by an hour) value too.

Comment: @naxa: if `mktime()` doesn't ignore `tm_isdst` on the given platform (it does on mine) then `fromtimestamp()` definitely looses the info: the returned *naive* `datetime` object representing local time may be ambiguous (timestamp -> local time is deterministic (if we ignore leap seconds) but `local time -> timestamp may be ambiguous e.g., during end-of-DST transition). Also, `fromtimestamp()` may choose a wrong utc offset if the it doesn't use a historical tz database.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the specific problem I was referring to is that a non-DST struct_time in the summer is always converted to a DST datetime by this method: `datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime((2015,6,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)))` -> `datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 1, 1, 0)`.  

This may be what you want, but it caused me problems. You're right in that there are further problems around the spec of `mktime()` and how historical tz data is handled. Really this all goes to show that (as pointed out by @lysdexia), datetime conversion is complicated and you need to think carefully about it.

Comment: @richvdh: incorrect. `mktime()` on my platform *always* returns the correct result (including DST/non-DST) if input time struct is not ambiguous (or non-existent) i.e., it may be wrong only *during* DST transitions (it ignores input `tm_isdst`) (that is why `pytz.timezone.localize()` method has `is_dst` parameter: to allow disambiguation) or around a positive leap second insertion. I get `datetime(2015,6,1,0,0)` (not `datetime(2015,6,1,1,0)`) on my machine (there is no DST transition at that time in my local timezone).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Not incorrect. I didn't say anything returned the wrong result; merely that there can be an implicit conversion from non-DST to DST-corrected times. 2015/06/01 isn't a DST transition in my timezone either; it is in the middle of the DST period, which is why `datetime.fromtimestamp()` converts it to DST-corrected time.

Comment: @richvdh: I can reproduce 1am result with `America/New_York` timezone. It is incorrect to pass `tm_isdst=0` for that day (`2015-06-01`) in that timezone. If you pass the expected for that date `1` or `-1` (to allow `mktime()` to figure out by itself the correct `tm_isdst` value) then `mktime()` returns the correct timestamp. I was wrong: `mktime()` may also return a wrong result given a wrong input even if there is no DST transition at that date. `fromtimestamp()` works correctly for that date on my system.

Comment: "OverflowError: mktime argument out of range" when I try to call mktime on my struct_time

Comment: @mlissner What is the solution prior to the year 1900?

Comment: Careful, this will convert to your specific timezone

Comment: In many cases if the `time_struct` was produced by something like a `time.strptime` call, you can bypass the conversion by simply using `datetime.strptime` instead. That'll put your date in the desired format as a `datetime.datetime` object.

Answer (score 146):

Like this:

```py
import time, datetime
st = time.localtime()

dt = datetime.datetime(*st[:6])

print(dt)
```

which prints `2009-11-08 20:32:35`.

Update: if you want to include any timezone information from the `struct_time` value, you could use this method:

```
def datetime_of_struct_time(st: time.struct_time) -> datetime.datetime:
    "Convert a struct_time to datetime maintaining timezone information when present"
    tz = None
    if st.tm_gmtoff is not None:
        tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=st.tm_gmtoff))
    # datetime doesn't like leap seconds so just truncate to 59 seconds
    if st.tm_sec in {60, 61}:
        return datetime.datetime(*st[:5], 59, tzinfo=tz)
    return datetime.datetime(*st[:6], tzinfo=tz)
```

Which could be used with the `struct_time` value from above:

```
print(datetime_of_struct_time(st))
```

printing `2009-11-08 20:32:35-04:00`.

Comment: Don't forget to #import time, datetime

Comment: @jhwist - some things people can be trusted to figure it out on their own :)

Comment: what does * in front of structTime do?

Comment: @rodling the `*` and `**` syntax allows you to expand a listy or dicty type object in to separate arguments - it's one of my favourite pieces of Python lovelyness. See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists for more info

Comment: @jhwist importing `time` isn't needed if you're already given a `time.struct_time` object.

Comment: Just remember this will give you a ValueError if the struct_time has a leapsecond, eg: `t=time.strptime("30 Jun 1997 22:59:60", "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"); datetime.datetime(*t[:6])`

Comment: @berdario: to return values compatible with `datetime`: `datetime(*t[:5]+(min(t[5], 59),))` e.g., to accept `"2015-06-30 16:59:60 PDT"`.

Comment: Note this also doesn't handle timezones.

Comment: @mlissner have added a variant that includes timezone information

Comment: @berdario my variant won't give a `ValueError` for leap seconds, but still allows a exception to be thrown for invalid second values.  e.g. it's possible to construct a`struct_time` value includes `tm_sec=67` which seems useful to fail on

Answer (score 44):

This is not a direct answer to your question (which was answered pretty well already). However, having had times bite me on the fundament several times, I cannot stress enough that it would behoove you to look closely at what your time.struct_time object is providing, vs. what other time fields may have.

Assuming you have both a time.struct_time object, and some other date/time string, compare the two, and be sure you are not losing data and inadvertently creating a naive datetime object, when you can do otherwise.

For example, the excellent feedparser module will return a "published" field and may return a time.struct_time object in its "published_parsed" field:

```
time.struct_time(
    tm_year=2013, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=9, 
    tm_hour=23, tm_min=57, tm_sec=42, 
    tm_wday=0, tm_yday=252, tm_isdst=0,
)
```

Now note what you actually get with the "published" field.

```
Mon, 09 Sep 2013 19:57:42 -0400
```

By [Stallman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman)'s Beard! Timezone information!

In this case, the lazy man might want to use the excellent dateutil module to keep the timezone information:

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse(entry["published"])
print "published", entry["published"])
print "dt", dt
print "utcoffset", dt.utcoffset()
print "tzinfo", dt.tzinfo
print "dst", dt.dst()
```

which gives us:

```
published Mon, 09 Sep 2013 19:57:42 -0400
dt 2013-09-09 19:57:42-04:00
utcoffset -1 day, 20:00:00
tzinfo tzoffset(None, -14400)
dst 0:00:00
```

One could then use the timezone-aware datetime object to normalize all time to UTC or whatever you think is awesome.

Comment: All the `*_parsed` fields from feedparsed are already normalized to UTC as can be checked in [the date parsing documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/date-parsing.html?highlight=utc#supporting-additional-date-formats) so this is redundant.

Comment: @itorres: If I understand it, this answer is not about normalizing to UTC, but about keeping the timezone information in a `datetime` object which is lost when `feedparser` parses raw string dates.

Comment: cant you do this without using a third party library?