# Python time differences

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have two time objects.

Example

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=24, tm_hour=19, tm_min=13, tm_sec=37, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=267, tm_isdst=-1)

time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=25, tm_hour=13, tm_min=7, tm_sec=25, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=268, tm_isdst=-1)
```

I want to have the difference of those two. How could I do that?
I need minutes and seconds only, as well as the duration of those two.

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object

Comment: timezone-aware answer: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Time` instances do not support the subtraction operation. Given that one way to solve this would be to convert the time to seconds since epoch and then find the difference, use:

```
>>> t1 = time.localtime()
>>> t1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=10, tm_min=12, tm_sec=27, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=286, tm_isdst=0)
>>> t2 = time.gmtime()
>>> t2
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=4, tm_min=42, tm_sec=37, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=286, tm_isdst=0)

>>> (time.mktime(t1) - time.mktime(t2)) / 60
329.83333333333331
```

Comment: In python 3 the mktime function returns the number of seconds since the Epoch and therefore no need to divide by 60.

Comment: local time may be ambiguous therefore `mktime()` may return a wrong result (50% chance during end-of-DST transitions, or just wrong for past dates if historical tz database is not used). It is incorrect to pass it UTC time (the result of `gmtime()`) unless the local timezone is UTC.

Comment: @AdamOren: `mktime()` *always* returns "seconds sicne the epoch". `/60` returns number of minutes as OP asks. I would use `minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)` to get minutes, seconds separately or use `timedelta` as [@jweyrich suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920862/4279).

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> t1 = time.mktime(time.strptime("10 Oct 10", "%d %b %y"))
>>> t2 = time.mktime(time.strptime("15 Oct 10", "%d %b %y"))
>>> print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=t2-t1))
5 days, 0:00:00
```

Comment: Doesn't work for Python 3.6: `errorMessage: "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time`

Comment: @Suncatcher huh? It works fine with python3 - see http://imgur.com/a/3rbhW

Comment: Yeah, mea culpa. I passed the wrong arguments. BTW, is there simpler way directly with `time.struct_time` type? Without converting to `mktime`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian your point being that it would return a wrong result when you provide 2 timestamps that comprehend a transition from DST to non-DST or vice-versa. Agreed.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "comprehend a transition". Click the link in my comment above. It describes explicitly when mktime fails.

Comment: Let's say your TZ is currently in DST, and at midnight it will transition to non-DST. Assume you're working with timestamp A from today, and timestamp B from tomorrow - `mktime` may not be aware of the DST transition, and would therefore return a time struct that is off by 1 hour, which will propagate the error to the `B - A` subtraction as well - The subtraction result will be off-by-1 hour. Is that it or I didn't understand your point (from your answer)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `time.mktime(t)` with the struct_time object (passed as "t") to convert it to a "seconds since epoch" floating point value.  Then you can subtract those to get difference in seconds, and divide by 60 to get difference in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to find the time difference between any two dates (no better than the previous solution, I guess):

```
 >>> import datetime
 >>> dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("10 Oct 10", "%d %b %y")
 >>> dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("15 Oct 10", "%d %b %y")
 >>> (dt2 - dt1).days
 5
 >>> (dt2 - dt1).seconds
 0
 >>>
```

It will give the difference in days or seconds or combination of that. The type for (dt2 - dt1) is datetime.timedelta. Look in the [library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for further details.