# Populating a Django DateTimeField with feedparser

Tags: python, django, rss, date, feedparser

I'm attempting to read my school's athletics/activities calendar, available in iCal or RSS format, into a Django Events model using feedparser.

Everything works, except the dates. Feedparser populates item.updated_parsed with a "9-tuple" but I can't figure out how to make this into something Django will accept in a DateTimeField. (I've used those before, but they've only ever been populated by datetime.datetime.now()).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Covert the `time.struct_time` object into a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(item['updated_parsed']))
```

Comment: This is fine. If you want to throw away the timezone info.

Answer (score 2):

Well the [Django DateTime field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) accepts python [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects so you have to convert from what Feedparser is providing you, and a datetime object. That's easy enough:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_object = datetime(nine_tuple[:8])
```

**EDIT:**
[How do you convert a Python time.struct_time object into a datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object)

Comment: This straight-up doesn't work. `datetime` doesn't accept a tuple as input. You *can* do `datetime(*item.updated_parsed[:7])`, but, natch, that drops the timezone info again.