# How to get RSS date using Universal Feed Parser

Tags: python, xml, rss

I have a RSS feed which have the data in the following format:

```
<item> 
    <title><![CDATA[à¨ç·à«çµàµÍÃì-JETSETER-»Å×éÁ-½Ñ¹à»ç¹¨ÃÔ§-¤Í¹àÊÔÃìµãË­è¤ÃÑé§áÃ¡ã¹ªÕÇÔµ-REDioactive-Presents-Jetseter-Music-Inspiration-Concert ]]></title>
     <link>http://www.thaiticketmajor.com/»ÃÐªÒÊÑÁ¾Ñ¹¸ìÅÙ¡¤éÒ/à¨ç·à«çµàµÍÃì-JETSETER-»Å×éÁ-½Ñ¹à»ç¹¨ÃÔ§-¤Í¹àÊÔÃìµãË­è¤ÃÑé§áÃ¡ã¹ªÕÇÔµ-REDioactive-Presents-Jetseter-Music-Inspiration-Concert-1012.html</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.thaiticketmajor.com/»ÃÐªÒÊÑÁ¾Ñ¹¸ìÅÙ¡¤éÒ/à¨ç·à«çµàµÍÃì-JETSETER-»Å×éÁ-½Ñ¹à»ç¹¨ÃÔ§-¤Í¹àÊÔÃìµãË­è¤ÃÑé§áÃ¡ã¹ªÕÇÔµ-REDioactive-Presents-Jetseter-Music-Inspiration-Concert-1012.html</guid>
        <pubDate>Fri, 30 Sep 2011 12:06:38 +0700</pubDate> 
        <description><![CDATA[<img src="http://www.majorcineplex.com/cropImage.php?imgName=http://www.thaiticketmajor.com/bus/imgUpload/newsThumb1012_jet-sm.jpg&w=70&h=33;c:width=50,height=50;file:rssimg.jpg"/>  ¾º¡Ñº¤Í¹àÊÔÃìµãË­èàµçÁÃÙ»áºº¤ÃÑé§áÃ¡¢Í§ Ç§à¨ç·à«çµàµÍÃì (JETSET'ER) ! ! ! Ç§´¹µÃÕ·Õè¼ÊÁ¼ÊÒ¹¤ÇÒÁÊ¹Ø¡¡Ñºà¾Å§à¾ÃÒÐ¿Ñ§ÊºÒÂàÍÒäÇé´éÇÂ¡Ñ¹ÍÂèÒ§Å§µÑÇ ]]></description>

</item>
```

Now I want the date value that is present in pubDate, and I tried that by using :

```
for entry in RSS_FEED.entries:
        FEED_TITLE = entry.title
        FEED_DESCRIPTION = entry.description
        FEED_DATE = entry.pubDate
```

which result in error :

```
raise AttributeError, "object has no attribute '%s'" % key
```

then I tried Universal Feed Parser document and try using:

```
FEED_DATE = str(entry.updated_parsed)
```

Though I am not getting any error this time , but I am not getting the actual date tim ein pubDate field instead I am getting the values as below:

> Datetime.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=11, tm_min=19, tm_sec=4, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=273,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the format of a [`time.struct_time` class](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time).

You can [convert it to a datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object), or just access the properties, however you desire.