# Google App Engine SDK: System time different from the computer time

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

In Google App Engine, I used `nowTime = datetime.datetime.now()` to get the system time. However, I found it is different from the computer system time. For example, `nowTime` is `2012-12-20 14:44:30.910192`, but my computer system time is `2012-12-20 22:44`. There is an eight-hour difference. Is it because of the time zone? Where does Google App Engine SDK get time from? Thanks.

Comment: Remember that your users may be in totally different time zones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://timezones.appspot.com/ - GAE time zones will always be in `UTC`, which is why you are seeing the 8-hour difference. Per the site:

> The runtime's TZ environment variable is set to UTC, and can't be
>   changed. Timestamps returned by e.g. time.time() and
>   datetime.datetime.now() will always be in UTC. Similarly, datetime
>   properties in the datastore will always be stored and returned as UTC.
>
> You can change the time zone of a datetime in memory with the
>   astimezone() method. If datetime's tzinfo member isn't set, you'll
>   first need to set it to a UTC tzinfo with the replace() method.

You can also see it documented [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#datetime), with an example of how to do special handling.

Comment: No wonder! Thanks. BTW, how do I change the time into UTC? I need to measure time length by: datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @Yuan-LiangTang Ha, time stuff still baffles me, regardless of how much time I spend reading about it :) One thing you can try is taking the current time (`t = time.time()`), converting it into UTC by doing `utc = time.gmtime(t)`, feeding it into `mktime` to get seconds since the epoch (`time.mktime(utc)`) and then feeding that into `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` to get a `datetime` object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object for a better overview, and good luck with everything!

Comment: @Greg Ha, yeah, if he doesn't need the microseconds (which I'm assuming he doesn't), that is a much better way to go (assuming shorter, easier to digest and faster to implement is better, of course :) ).