# Compare datetime.datetime to time.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-2.4, strptime

I have the following code:

```
nowtime = datetime.datetime.now()
newTime = time.strptime(myTimestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if(newTime > nowTime):
  #do some stuff
```

Of course, my comparison fails with a TypeError, "can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple.". Note that I am using an older version of Python that doesn't have datetime.strptime(). How can I get this comparison to work?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object ?

Comment: Please state the exact (old) python version so we can browse the docs and seek a proper remedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

> This is equivalent to `datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`.

For older Python versions (e.g. 2.3 or 2.4), use just that:

```
import datetime
import time

datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime(myTimestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:6]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> myTimestring = '2013-01-01 12:42:23'
>>> datetime.datetime(*(time.strptime(myTimestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:6]))
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 12, 42, 23)
```