# datetime difference in python

Tags: python, datetime

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
     if proc.name == "monit":
         current_time = time.localtime()
         proc_start_time = time.localtime(proc.create_time)
         print (current_time - proc_start_time).seconds
```

I am not able to find difference between two datetimes. Can't subtract them give Error -
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'**

Answer (score 4):

`current_time` and `proc_start_time` are strings because that is what `strftime` returns.

You'll want to get rid of `current_time`, and make `proc_start_time = time.localtime(proc.create_time)`. Now you have two time objects, which will allow you to find the difference.

Comment: I made two times as objs of same type -              current_time = time.localtime();
proc_start_time =  time.localtime(proc.create_time); print  (current_time - proc_start_time).seconds .Still gives error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'

Comment: @script_kiddie I've never worked with those type of objects, but I have worked with datetime objects. If you convert those using [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object), you should be able to. Sorry I couldn't give a better answer

Comment: dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(proc_start_time))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp' , where proc_start_time is time.struct_time object

Comment: @script_kiddie If you did `import datetime`, then you need to put `datetime.datetime` at the beginning

Comment: :current_time = datetime.datetime.today();
proc_start_time =  time.localtime(proc.create_time);
 dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(proc_start_time));
 print (current_time - dt).seconds gives me 13736 while print (current_time - dt).days gives me 39 .. how come this mismatch ?

Comment: @script_kiddie I'm sorry, I have no idea.