# python string to datetime, find yesterday then back to string

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to do the following:

1. read a date from a file (the format of the date is %Y-%m-%d)
2. convert a string into a datetime obj (i'm doing this with strptime)
3. get the day **prior** to the datetime
4. convert the day prior (look_back) back into a string with a given
   format

Steps 1 & 2 are not an issue, which I accomplish like so:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now() #checks current datetime

### READ LAST RUN DATETIME ###
try:
    test = open("last_settings.ini", "r") #opens file in read mode
    print "Name of the file: ", test.name

    last_run = test.read(10); # just reads the date
    print "Program was last run: %s" % last_run
    test.close()
    firstRun = 'False'
except:
    print "Settings file does not exist"
    #test = open("last_settings.ini", "w+") #creates the file
    #test.close()

    #first_run = 'True'
    #look_back = str(now-timedelta(days=14)) #sets initial lookBack date of two weeks
    #print "Pulling down all paid invoices from date " + look_back


### 24 hour lookback ###
look_back = time.strptime(last_run, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, every method I've tried for getting the date prior to the give date (#3 above) throws an error.  My code:

```
look_back = look_back-timedelta(days=1)
```

The error:

```
look_back = look_back-timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Have ideas about how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert a python time.struct_time object into a datetime object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object). You must convert you `time.struct_time` to a `datetime`

Comment: @Rod: no, just use `datetime.strptime()` to parse the date instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` objects have a [`strptime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) *as well*:

```
read_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_run, '%Y-%m-%d')
previous_day = read_date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
formatted_previous_day = previous_day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Aaaaah, I was comparing a time object to a datetime object, thereby throwing an error.  Makes sense!