# Convert date and time from scraped text to datetime format

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, scrapy

I'm making a news aggregator using Python and Scrapy and cannot find an answer for exactly what I'm trying to do.

I am scraping a line of text from an article, a publish time, like so:

```
item['published'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="date"]/text()').extract()
```

This is what I'm getting back (there is no ISO date on the site, as there are some of the others I'm scraping for this project):

```
Last Updated: Tuesday, March 11, 2014
```

I need to put these dates and times into a format that I can also convert other sources' publish times and so that I can order them chronologically later via that key in the JSON feed.

So with a date in that format, how can I convert it to a usable form? I'd like in the end to have all the ISO dates and those written-out text formats converted to something like this:

```
Published: 2:15 p.m., March 15, 2014.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use `dateutil.parser.parse`. Here's [the documentation](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2). It handles a variety of formats. On debian-style OSes, it's available in the package python-dateutil.

If this answer doesn't fully answer your question, please comment and I'll try to updated it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: jrennie's solution above is way cleaner than mine.

This works. I use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) in order to get a solution. Note, since there is no hh:mm data in the original string, I can't output any hh:mm data like you did in your example.

Step by step solution:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = "Last Updated: Tuesday, March 11, 2014"
>>> t = t.rsplit(' ',4)[1:5] # Get a list of the relevant date fields
['Tuesday,', 'March', '11,', '2014']
>>> t = ' '.join(t) # Turn t into a string so we can use strptime
'Tuesday, March 11, 2014'
>>> t = time.strptime(t, "%A, %B %d, %Y") # Use strptime
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=70, tm_isdst=-1)
```

One liner:

```
import time

t = "Last Updated: Tuesday, March 11, 2014"
time.strptime(' '.join(t.rsplit(' ',4)[1:5]), "%A, %B %d, %Y")
```

This results a struct_time. You may end up wanting [convert these to datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object), depending on how you wish to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

Today a good way to do that is to use the dateparser project from the scrapy team: https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser