# Python - convert elapsed time to seconds when format is not consistent

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to identify the number of seconds that have elapsed given a time string. These time strings are not always consistent.

Examples:

'01:02' = 1 minute, 2 seconds = 62 seconds

'1-11:01:02' = 1 day, 11 hours, 1 minute, 2 seconds = 126062 seconds

I have tried time.strptime, but I didn't see a way to elegantly perform this operation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it is to gather all possible formats in an array and check the time_str against them:

```
 time_formats = ["%m-%d:%H:%M","%H:%M"]
 time_val = None

 for fmt in time_formats:
    try:
      time_val = time.strptime(time_str,fmt)
    except:
      pass

 if time_val is None:
      print "No matching format found"
```

This try-catch structure is consistent with the EAFP principle in python. http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

Comment: does it make sense to represent *elapsed time* as `time.struct_time()`? `datetime.timedelta()` could be used instead

Comment: problem is, timedelta doesn't have this strptime capability. One can convert between these different formats as described in the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object