# Python pandas read excel - create index from two columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I regularly face an issue when I have an excel file which looks like the following:

```
 Date     ,      Hour

 2015-12-15 ,      1
```

(Please note that this data are read from excel so the date is in excel whatever format)

Now I tried:

```
df2=pd.read_excel(name, sheetname=0,skiprows=17, parse_dates="Date")
df2["test"]=df2.apply(lambda val: val["Date"]+timedelta(hours=int(df2["Hour"])-1))
```

However, here I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'Date', ' occured at index Date'
```

My df2 have the following types:

```
Date:  datetime64
Hour:  object
```

In addition I tried:

```
df2.set_index(df2["Date"]+df2["Hour"])
```

but without success.

Does anybody has a clue how to avoid this error, or how to get an index column in the following format:

```
2015-12-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would have worked if  instead of;

```
df2["test"]=df2.apply(lambda val: val["Date"]+timedelta(hours=int(df2["Hour"])-1))
```

you should have used;

```
df2["test"]=df2.apply(lambda val: val["Date"]+timedelta(hours=int(df2["Hour"])-1), axis=1)
```

This will make sure that .apply works on an entire pandas dataframe instead of series.

Answer (score 1):

For this xlsx file:

```
Date        Hour
12/12/2015  1
12/13/2015  2
12/14/2015  3
12/15/2015  4
12/16/2015  5
12/17/2015  6
```

This worked for me:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_excel('dates.xlsx')

index_candidate = [(str(x).split()[0]+' '+str(y)) for x,y in zip(df2['Date'],df2['Hour'])]
index_candidate = [datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H') for a in index_candidate]

df2.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(index_candidate),inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, ufnfortunately I got the error that datetime.time has no attribute mktime. What does mktime do? thanks

Comment: oops, sorry for that, time and datetime are not the same, I hink this import should fix it: from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime, I got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object)

Comment: hm.. thanks I figured that out myself but then I got an error: "tuple or struct_time argument required...

Comment: Check my new answer, let me know if it works for you