# How do I access pubDate for RSS items using Python feedparser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rss, feedparser, rss2

In [this example RSS feed](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/examples/rss2sample.xml), the [optional item element **pubDate**](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html#ltpubdategtSubelementOfLtitemgt) is included in all entries. But it is not available as a item element in the Python module [feedparser](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/index.html). This code:

```
import feedparser
rss_object = feedparser.parse("http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/examples/rss2sample.xml")
for entry in rss_object.entries:
    print entry.pubDate
```

Causes the error `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'pubDate'` but I can successfully do `print entry.description` and see the contents of all the description tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`feedparser` is an opinionated parser, not simply returning XML in a dictionary. The text of `pubDate` is available as [`entries[i].published`](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-published.html?highlight=pubdate).

> The date this entry was first published, as a string in the same format as it was published in the original feed.

Working code:

```
for entry in rss_object.entries:
    print entry.published
```

Note: `published` is extracted from one of several possible XML tags depending on the format of the feed. See [the reference manual](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-entry-published.html?highlight=pubdate) for a list.

This manual also claims the pubDate element is parsed "as a date" in `entries[i].published_parsed`. What's in `published_parsed` is a `time.struct_time` object; you may want to [re-parse the date yourself to maintain time zone information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18726020/1487413), if the original feed included time zones.

Comment: Gosh. I wish I'd noticed this earlier when using feedparser. Everything else maps to standard RSS tags, so I was missing dates all the time.