# Pandas to_datetime() issue with specific datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, nginx

I would like to convert my dataframe from this string to a usable date-time format

```
01/May/2016:06:38:13 +0100
```

I'm currently using `Python V 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0(64-bit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
df.time = df.time.apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.strptime(x, '%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %z'))))
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
[How do you convert a Python time.struct_time object into a datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object)

Comment: ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%I:%M:%S %z'

Comment: The 'z' directive is currently not supported by pandas `to_datetime` (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13486)

Comment: @CMari check it out again

Answer (score 1):

From [Joris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434025/pandas-to-datetime-issue-with-specific-datetime-format#38434610) comment this should do it using [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
a='01/May/2016:06:38:13 +0100'

In[27]:parse(a.replace(':', ' ', 1))
Out[27]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 6, 38, 13, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
```