# Adding a day in time.struct_time object

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am using a time.struct_time to set up the date and time and I want to add to the next day using a python script.

I am using following code:

```
date_1 = "31/08/2017 10:30PM"
time_1 = time.strptime(date_1, '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
```

Output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=22, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=243, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Now I want to add 1 day to this date. I used the following code:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=22, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=243, tm_isdst=-1)
```

I am new on this, so can you please show me an example how I could add to the next day date using with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I'm not sure if there even is a (clean) way. The data of a struct_time object are stored as tuples, so they are immutable. This means they can't really be modified in place.

I think you should be using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module instead, like so:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_1 = "31/08/2017 10:30PM"
>>> time_1 = datetime.strptime(date_1, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p")
>>> time_1
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 31, 22, 30)
```

You can then add a month like so:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> time_1 + relativedelta(months=1)
datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 30, 22, 30)
```

If you want to add a single day, then use `datetime.timedelta()`, which deals with the month's number of days:

```
from datetime import timedelta
time_1 + timedelta(days=1)
```

The reason I didn't use this above is because `timedelta()` doesn't take months as an argument

---

If you wish to convert it back to a string, then you use the [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function like so:

```
>>> new_time_1 = time_1 + relativedelta(months=1)
>>> print(datetime.strftime(new_time_1, '%d/%m/%Y'))
30/09/2017
>>> print(datetime.strftime(time_1, '%d/%m/%Y'))
31/08/2017
```

---

If for some reason you need to use the `time` module (say for one part of your code) but you want to convert it to the `datetime` object (for reasons like this), then I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object) question.

Comment: thank you very much for this, I'm stored the date_1 string in the list so I could output them when I use `date_1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in self.date_1)`. How I can get the date `31/08/2017` from the string and how I add it to the next day to make it show `1/09/2017` if there is possible to do in a different way?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel Check my edit... does that answer your question?

Comment: No not really, when you add the day it should add to the next month if my day is 29, 30, 31 or whatever its. Are there a way to do that without add the month, just the day?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel Ah, that's where you'd do `from datetime import timedelta; time_1 + timedelta(days=1)`. I didn't use this in my original answer since `timedelta` doesn't take a `months` argument

Comment: Oh I see, so how would I know I need to add to the next month as some months has `30` and some months has `31`?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel That honestly depends on what you're trying to do. Do you always want this certain date to be the last day of the month?

Comment: I am trying to add to the next day and if the day is 30 or 31 then add 1 for the next month. Is that possible to do that in one line?  so what about this `dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(epg_time_1))` as I get the output `2017-08-31 22:30:00`, is that possible to add the next day to make it to show `2017-09-01 22:30:00`?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel Then all you need to do is `dt + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`. The function deals with months having 30/31 days (and 28 for feb)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) as explained in this question: [Adding 5 days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python#6871482)