# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "datetime.timedelta") to tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I need some help with my code. I have got an error when I am trying to add 30 mins with `getTime3`.

```
import datetime
import time

getTime3 = '12:30AM'
dt3 = time.strptime(getTime3, '%I:%M%p')
test_time = dt3 + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)

print test_time
```

The error are jumping on this line:

```
test_time = dt3 + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)
```

Here is what `dt3` show the struct_time object:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Here is what `test_time` show the object without the `dt3`:

```
0:30:00
```

Can you please help me with how I could correct the error to allow me to add the minutes?

Comment: you're using the `time` version of `strptime`, which [returns a `struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime); you probably want to be using the `datetime` version of `strptime`, [which returns a `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Comment: @Hamms I am sorry but i cant use datetime version of strptime because the application I am running will only allow me to use `time` version of strtime which it works fine.

Comment: @Hamms please see the update in my question

Comment: That seems pretty strange to me, but in that case I'd just [convert the struct_time to a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-python-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to manipulate the `time.struct_time` type is by converting it to seconds since epoch, and vice versa.

In your particular case, you want to add 30 minutes, that will be `30 * 60` seconds:

```
test_time = time.localtime(time.mktime(dt3) + 30*60))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use just [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module for better handling dates and times:

```py
import datetime

format = '%I:%M%p'
getTime3 = '12:30AM'
dt3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(getTime3, format)
test_time = dt3 + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 30)

print(test_time.time().strftime(format))
```