# How to convert time object to datetime object in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time

I have timestamp which is a `time` object and trying to convert it to a `datetime` object because `datetime` has stonger capabilities and I need to use some function that only `datetime` has.
The reason I'm starting with `time` is because `datetime` doesn't support milliseconds which the original string contains.

What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: "*because datetime doesn't support milliseconds* - what makes you think that? Just because there is no *attribute* "milliseconds" doesn't mean you cannot work with them - just multiply by 10^3 and use the microseconds attribute ;-)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime `time.strftime` doesn't support printing milli or microsecond. unlike `datetime.strftime` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior . (and the same about `strptime`..)

Comment: your question says nothing about `strftime`. please clarify if this should be helpful for others.

Comment: btw. there also seems to be confusion about datetime and time objects vs. the modules with the same name. There is e.g. a datetime.time class, where you can use strftime without problems to create a string with milliseconds precision: `datetime.time(1,2,3,444000).strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]`

Comment: They question talks about the broad issue of converting objects between the two common packages used when working with time and dates, I looked the simple way to convert the object in order to apply it in my specific use case (which uses `strftime` and `strptime` for different reasons..). This is the reason I posted the question and answer this way, for someone looking for the broader question be able to solve it easily

Comment: The broad answer is: preferably use the datetime module exclusively. And again, the term `time object` is confusing as described above. You seem to mean `time.struct_time object`. And I think that has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1697815/10197418).

Comment: I referred it as time object because it's the return value of `time.strptime`.. BUT, you are right.. I'll flag the question as duplicate. Thanks for the interesting discussion

Answer (score 0):

assuming timestamp is an `time` object and datetimestamp will be the `datetime` object:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time

timestamp = time.strptime('2022-03-02 02:45:12.123', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetimestamp = datetime(*timestamp[:5])
```

It works because time is actually a tuple with the following structure `(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds....)`, and the `datetime` `__init__` expects the same sequence of variables

Comment: `timestamp` is a [time.struct_time object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) for clarification. But why not simply `datetimestamp = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-03-02 02:45:12.123')` ?