# Parsing date with timezone from an email?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, format, rfc5322

I am trying to retrieve date from an email. At first it's easy:

```
message = email.parser.Parser().parse(file)
date = message['Date']
print date
```

and I receive:

```
'Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100'
```

But I need a nice datetime object, so I use:

```
datetime.strptime('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

which raises `ValueError, since %Z isn't format for +0100`. But I can't find proper format for timezone in the documentation, there is only this `%Z` for zone. Can someone help me on that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`email.utils` has a [`parsedate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parsedate) function for the RFC 2822 format, which as far as I know is not deprecated.

```
>>> import email.utils
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100')
(2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2, 0, 1, -1)
>>> time.mktime((2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2, 0, 1, -1))
1258378322.0
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1258378322.0)
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2)
```

Please note, however, that the `parsedate` method does not take into account the time zone and [`time.mktime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.mktime) always expects a local time tuple.

```
>>> (time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0900')) ==
... time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100'))
True
```

So you'll still need to parse out the time zone and take into account the local time difference, too:

```
>>> REMOTE_TIME_ZONE_OFFSET = +9 * 60 * 60
>>> (time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0900')) +
... time.timezone - REMOTE_TIME_ZONE_OFFSET)
1258410122.0
```

Comment: Yep, those functions seems to have been moved to utils and email is fine to use. Thanks.

Comment: That won't yield an accurate value. `time.mktime` assumes a local time tuple, and the parsedate function does not take into account the time zone:`time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0900')) == time.mktime(email.utils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100'))` returns `True`. Tagging @gruszczy in case he's relying on this method.

Comment: `mktime + timezone` may produce wrong values for past dates or if the timezone has DST transitions: `time.timezone != time.altzone`. Use `tt = parsedate_tz(date_str); timestamp = calendar.timegm(tt) - tt[9]` instead.

Comment: In more recent versions of python you can also use `email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime`

Answer (score 38):

Use [`email.utils.parsedate_tz(date)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz):

```
msg=email.message_from_file(open(file_name))
date=None
date_str=msg.get('date')
if date_str:
    date_tuple=email.utils.parsedate_tz(date_str)
    if date_tuple:
        date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
if date:
    ... # valid date found
```

Comment: `mktime_tz` may fail on Python before 2.7.4 if the local timezone had different UTC offset at `date_tuple`. [Use `calendar.timegm()` directly in this case.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790795/python-parsing-date-with-timezone-from-an-email#comment35349147_1790885)

Comment: This returns a naive `datetime` in UTC. To make it aware, you could provide a time zone as the second parameter to `fromtimestamp`. In python 3, that's easy: `datetime.timezone.utc`. In python 2.7, you'd need to [implement a UTC `tzinfo` class](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo) and provide that.

Comment: In python 3.7 parsedate_tz have not counted tz shift in datetime '2019-03-14 20:43:56 +0300' and just returned a naive '2019-03-14 20:43:56'. Although email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime from @jfs answer solved the problem and returned tz-aware object.

Answer (score 17):

For python 3.3+ you can use **[parsedate_to_datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime)** function:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
>>> parsedate_to_datetime('Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100')
...
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

Official documentation:

> The inverse of format_datetime(). Performs the same function as
>   parsedate(), but on success returns a datetime. If the input date has
>   a timezone of -0000, the datetime will be a naive datetime, and if the
>   date is conforming to the RFCs it will represent a time in UTC but
>   with no indication of the actual source timezone of the message the
>   date comes from. If the input date has any other valid timezone
>   offset, the datetime will be an aware datetime with the corresponding
>   a timezone tzinfo. New in version 3.3.

Answer (score 12):

In Python 3.3+, `email` message can parse the headers for you:

```
import email
import email.policy

headers = email.message_from_file(file, policy=email.policy.default)
print(headers.get('date').datetime)
# -> 2009-11-16 13:32:02+01:00
```

Since Python 3.2+, it works if you replace `%Z` with `%z`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100", 
...                   "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2,
                  tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

Or using `email` package (Python 3.3+):

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
>>> parsedate_to_datetime("Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100")
datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 16, 13, 32, 2,
                  tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

if UTC offset is specified as `-0000` then it returns a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC otherwise it returns an aware datetime object with the corresponding `tzinfo` set.

To parse [rfc 5322 date-time string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3) on earlier Python versions (2.6+):

```
from calendar import timegm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, tzinfo
from email.utils import parsedate_tz

ZERO = timedelta(0)
time_string = 'Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100'
tt = parsedate_tz(time_string)
#NOTE: mktime_tz is broken on Python < 2.7.4,
#  see https://bugs.python.org/issue21267
timestamp = timegm(tt) - tt[9] # local time - utc offset == utc time
naive_utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=timestamp)
aware_utc_dt = naive_utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(ZERO, 'UTC'))
aware_dt = aware_utc_dt.astimezone(FixedOffset(timedelta(seconds=tt[9])))
print(aware_utc_dt)
print(aware_dt)
# -> 2009-11-16 12:32:02+00:00
# -> 2009-11-16 13:32:02+01:00
```

where [`FixedOffset` is based on `tzinfo` subclass from the `datetime` documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/4279):

```
class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    """Fixed UTC offset: `time = utc_time + utc_offset`."""
    def __init__(self, offset, name=None):
        self.__offset = offset
        if name is None:
            seconds = abs(offset).seconds
            assert abs(offset).days == 0
            hours, seconds = divmod(seconds, 3600)
            if offset < ZERO:
                hours = -hours
            minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
            assert seconds == 0
            #NOTE: the last part is to remind about deprecated POSIX
            #  GMT+h timezones that have the opposite sign in the
            #  name; the corresponding numeric value is not used e.g.,
            #  no minutes
            self.__name = '<%+03d%02d>GMT%+d' % (hours, minutes, -hours)
        else:
            self.__name = name
    def utcoffset(self, dt=None):
        return self.__offset
    def tzname(self, dt=None):
        return self.__name
    def dst(self, dt=None):
        return ZERO
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FixedOffset(%r, %r)' % (self.utcoffset(), self.tzname())
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
rfc822.parsedate_tz(date) # ?
```

More on RFC822, http://docs.python.org/library/rfc822.html

It's deprecated (parsedate_tz is now in [`email.utils.parsedate_tz`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz)), though.

But maybe these answers help:

- [How to parse dates with -0400 timezone string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101508/how-to-parse-dates-with-0400-timezone-string-in-python)
- [python time to age part 2, timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526406/python-time-to-age-part-2-timezones)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it, but it's deprecated.

Comment: This function is now known as email.utils.parsedate_tz(), FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Parses Nginx' format of "01/Jan/1999:13:59:59 +0400"
# Unfortunately, strptime doesn't support %z for the UTC offset (despite what
# the docs actually say), hence the need # for this function.
def parseDate(dateStr):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr[:-6], "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
    offsetDir = dateStr[-5]
    offsetHours = int(dateStr[-4:-2])
    offsetMins = int(dateStr[-2:])
    if offsetDir == "-":
        offsetHours = -offsetHours
        offsetMins = -offsetMins
    return date + datetime.timedelta(hours=offsetHours, minutes=offsetMins)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to get the correct local time, here is what I did:

```
from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime

mail_time_str = 'Mon, 16 Nov 2009 13:32:02 +0100'

local_time_str = datetime.fromtimestamp(parsedate_to_datetime(mail_time_str).timestamp()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print(local_time_str)
```

Answer (score -1):

## `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format...`

(note: I have to stick to python 2.7 in my case)

I have had a similar problem parsing commit dates from the output of `git log --date=iso8601` which actually isn't the ISO8601 format (hence the addition of `--date=iso8601-strict` in a later version).

Since I am using `django` I can leverage the utilities there.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateparse.py

```
>>> from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
>>> parse_datetime('2013-07-23T15:10:59.342107+01:00')
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 15, 10, 59, 342107, tzinfo=+0100)
```

Instead of `strptime` you could use your own regular expression.

Comment: it does not answer the question. You use *different* time format. Note: the time format in the question is defined in rfc 5322 (and its predessors) -- it can be parsed using `email.utils.parsedate_tz` on Python 2.7. Your format looks like rfc 3339. Both can be parsed using `dateutil.parser.parse()` on Python 2.  See [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, had you not deleted my answer on one of the duplicate question, I would not have posted my answer here. My problem was `strptime does not handle %z format`, I believe this is the same problem.

Comment: I *can't* delete someone's else answer by myself. Could you link to the corresponding question?