# How can I convert a timestamp string with timezone offset to local time?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert a string timestamp into a proper datetime object. The problem I am having is that there is a timezone offset and everything I am doing doesn't seem to work.

Ultimately I want to convert the string timestamp into a datetime object in my machines timezone.

```
# string timestamp     
date = "Fri, 16 Jul 2010 07:08:23 -0700"
```

Answer (score 10):

The [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package is handy for parsing date/times:

```
In [10]: date = u"Fri, 16 Jul 2010 07:08:23 -0700"

In [11]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [12]: parse(date)
Out[12]: datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 16, 7, 8, 23, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```

Finally, to convert into your local timezone,

```
In [13]: parse(date).astimezone(YOUR_LOCAL_TIMEZONE)
```

Comment: how do I take this and turn it into a time representation that matches my current timezone?

and thanks for that btw :)

Comment: Glad to help.  You can use the `astimezone` method of the datetime object that's returned by parse.  See this question for detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python

Comment: Dateutil rocks! parsed my string ("2013-10-22T21:56:00.000-03:00") without me having to provide a format string.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')` should work, but according to [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641) there are issues with the `%z` processing.  So you'll probably have to handle the timezone on your own:

```
import datetime

d = u"Fri, 16 Jul 2010 07:08:23 -0700"

d, tz_info = d[:-5], d[-5:]
neg, hours, minutes = tz_info[0], int(tz_info[1:3]), int(tz_info[3:])
if neg == '-':
    hours, minutes = hours * -1, minutes * -1

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S ')
print d
print d + datetime.timedelta(hours = hours, minutes = minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stdlib solution:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from email.utils import mktime_tz, parsedate_tz
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(u"Fri, 16 Jul 2010 07:08:23 -0700")))
datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 16, 16, 8, 23) # your local time may be different
```

See also, [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).

Note: `fromtimestamp()` may fail if the local timezone had different UTC offset in the past (2010) *and* if it does not use a historical timezone database on the given platform. To fix it, you could use [`tzlocal.get_localzone()`](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal), to get a `pytz` tzinfo object representing your local timezone. [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) provides access to the tz database in a portable manner:

```
>>> timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(u"Fri, 16 Jul 2010 07:08:23 -0700"))
>>> import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal
>>> str(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tzlocal.get_localzone()))
'2010-07-16 16:08:23+02:00'
```