# Find the epoch of the most recent midnight

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the epoch seconds for the most recent midnight in Python.

I found this: [What was midnight yesterday as an epoch time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594747/what-was-midnight-yesterday-as-an-epoch-time)

which has

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
midnight = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.min)
```

'midnight' is now the right time...but how do I get it into epoch seconds?  i.e., something like 1393997154 (or 1393997154.09)

Not saying the above the best approach.  In perl, I would

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = localtime(time);
$year += 1900;
return timelocal(0,0,0,$mday,$mon,$year);
```

...in other words, get the struct, change hour/min/sec, then convert it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert normal time format (yyyy-mm-dd hours:minutes:seconds) into epoch seconds, follow the code.

```
import datetime
import calendar
d = datetime.datetime(yyyy,mm,dd,hours,minutes,seconds)
calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
```

EX: To calculate epoch time for 2014-03-04 12:00:00,

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2014,03,04,12,00,00)
>>> calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
1393934400
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function with `%s`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today().strftime('%s')
'1393920000'
```

Comment: Interestingly, %s is not documented on the 2.7 datetime page, though it works.  Apparently it only does GM time, though, not localtime.

Comment: %s is not portable. It only works on systems where C library supports the strftime() library function (glibc).

Comment: Isn't Python always linked with glibc?

Answer (score 0):

If your epoch reference is `time.time()`, you can use :

```
now=list(time.localtime())
LocalMidnight=time.mktime(tuple(now[:3]+[0]*3+now[-3:]))
```