# How to convert datetime string to UTC to plot points on Highcharts

Tags: python, highcharts

I'm working on HighCharts Spline Irregular Data. Here the data is passed as

```
data: [
      [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
      [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
      ]
```

But, I'm sending the data from the python backend via AJAX call as

```
data: [
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 0   ],
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 1   ],
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 2   ],
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 3   ],
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 4   ],
      "2013-11-07 00:10:27", 5   ],
      ]
```

So, the data points does not gets plotted. How do I convert the datetime to UTC or any other format of datetime at the backend(python), which will enable Highcharts to plot the correct X and Y-axis points.?

Here is what I've tried.
Since the UTC time `Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27)` returns the number of seconds, hence I'm converting the time to the total number of secs passed since 1970-1-1 behind the scenes.

```
time = "2013-11-06 18:00:00"
time = ((datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

and then passing it to the UI., hence my data is send as

`[[1383760800.0, 1870.2000000000007], [1383762600.0, 0.30000000000000004], [1383761700.0, 4.299999999999802]]`

Now when I pass this data to the highcharts, the Y-axis shows correct value but the X-axis(on which the datetime needed to plotted) shows time as 05:52.

How can I correct it?

Here is my Highcharts code.

```
function comparison_chart(result) {
  var MAXPOINTS = 20;

  Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
          useUTC: false,
      }
  });

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
      load: function() {

          // set up the updating of the chart each second
          var series = this.series[0];


          setInterval(function() {
              var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                  y = Math.random();
              if(series.data.length > MAXPOINTS){
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);  
              }
              else{
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
              }



          },5000);
      },
  }

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Energy Chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var s;
                s = this.y + 'kWh';
            return s;
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Random data',
        data: result,
        showInLegend: true,

    }]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that HighCharts expects time series data to be given in milliseconds, not seconds so you will need to put in a multiplier of 1000.

You can convert from your strings to milliseconds since epoch like so:

```
>>> int(datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-11-07 00:10:27", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%s')) * 1000
1383811827000
```

Comment: So, you mean to say I should multiply this statement by 1000?

`time = ((datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()*1000  `

Comment: 1 question. What does `strftime('%s')` means?

Comment: Well, I would suggest looking at the docs for `time`, but it converts a datetime object to a string of the seconds since the epoch (Jan 1, 1970)

Comment: '%s' solution is os-dependent, see p.ex. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11743262/1265154)