# How to convert string date to a epoch timestamp in python

Tags: python

I have a string date as `2015-03-25T00:00:00Z`. How do I convert it to a unix epoch`1426636800000.0`

Are there any libraries in python to do that.

Comment: This looks like an ISO date and has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: Also, you can see some in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using time, for example.

So first you need to convert the string to time object (or you can use datetime alternatively as halex mentioned) and then get the seconds since epoch.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime('2015-03-25T00:00:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
1427241600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> time.strptime(string[, format])

```
import time

print time.strptime("2015-03-25T00:00:00Z","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3.3 or newer you can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-03-25T00:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ").timestamp() 
1427238000.0
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp' is the error getting thrown

Comment: @user2890683 Oh. I forgot to mention that [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) was introduced in Python 3.3. Seems like you are using Python2. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
timestamp = date_converter.string_to_timestamp("2015-03-25T00:00:00Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```