# Convert EST timestamp to GMT taking into account Daylight Savings

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I have a timestamp that represents milliseconds since 1970 `1432202088224` which translates to `Thursday, May 21, 2015 5:54:48 AM EDT`. I'd like to write a python function that converts that timestamp to milliseconds in GMT. I can't naively add four hours (`3600000` milliseconds) to the existing timestamp because half the year i'll be off by one hour.

I've tried writing a function using `datetime` and `pytz`

```
def convert_mills_GMT(milliseconds):
    converted_raw = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds/1000.0)
    date_eastern = eastern.localize(converted_raw, is_dst=True)
    date_utc = date_eastern.astimezone(utc)
    return int(date_utc.strftime("%s")) * 1000
```

using the input of `1432202088224` this function returns `1432220088000` which is `Thursday, May 21, 2015 10:54:48 AM EDT` when what I want is 9:54 AM. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use `.strftime("%s")`. It is not supported, and may silently fail.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743019/190597) Instead, to convert a UTC datetime to a timestamp use [one of the methods shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/190597) depending on your version of Python:

#### Python 3.3+:

```
timestamp = dt.timestamp()
```

#### Python3 (< 3.3):

```
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
timestamp = (dt - epoch) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

#### Python 2.7+:

```
timestamp = (dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

#### Python2 (< 2.7):

```
def totimestamp(dt, epoch=datetime(1970,1,1)):
    td = dt - epoch
    # return td.total_seconds()
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 10**6) / 10**6 
timestamp = totimestamp(dt.replace(tzinfo=None))
```

---

Therefore, your `convert_mills_GMT` should look like

```
def convert_mills_GMT(milliseconds, 
                      utc=pytz.utc,
                      eastern=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
):
    converted_raw = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds/1000.0)
    date_eastern = eastern.localize(converted_raw, is_dst=True)
    date_utc = date_eastern.astimezone(utc)
    timestamp = ...
    return int(timestamp) * 1000
```

---

For example, with Python2.7,

```
import datetime as DT
import pytz

def convert_mills_GMT(milliseconds, 
                      utc=pytz.utc,
                      eastern=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
):
    converted_raw = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(milliseconds/1000.0)
    date_eastern = eastern.localize(converted_raw, is_dst=True)
    date_utc = date_eastern.astimezone(utc)
    timestamp = ((date_utc.replace(tzinfo=None) - DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1))
                 .total_seconds())
    return int(timestamp) * 1000

print(DT.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(convert_mills_GMT(1432202088224)/1000.0))
```

prints

```
2015-05-21 09:54:48
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "EST timestamp". If you need "GMT timestamp" then you already have it.

To get UTC time from a POSIX timestamp given as number of milliseconds:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> timestamp = 1432202088224
>>> utc_time = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=timestamp)
>>> utc_time.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p UTC')
'Thursday, May 21, 2015 09:54:48 AM UTC'
```

We can check that the result is correct by converting the UTC time back to "EST" timezone:

```
>>> import pytz # $ pip install pytz
>>> est = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
>>> est.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z')
'Thursday, May 21, 2015 05:54:48 AM EDT'
```