# python the code strftime("%s") errors

Tags: python

THE python program is as follows, it errors:

> File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\group_download.py", line 31, in      getFeed
>       params += "&since=" + SINCE.strftime("%s")
>   
>     ValueError: Invalid format string

the program it seems `SINCE.strftime("%s")` is wrong, how to solve it?

```
SINCE = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(DAYS)

params = "?fields=permalink_url,from,story,type,message,link,created_time,updated_time,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)"

#Default paging limit
params += "&amp&limit=" + DEFAULT_LIMIT

#Time-based limit
params += "&amp;since=" + SINCE.strftime("%s")
graph_url = GRAPH_URL_PREFIX + group + "/feed" + params
```

Comment: Kindly post the complete code here

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it should be capital S:

```
params += "&amp;since=" + SINCE.strftime("%S")
                                           ^
```

Comment: when modify to capital S:it errors:File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\group_download.py", line 31, in getFeed
        params += "&amp;since=" + SINCE.strftime("%Ｓ")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\uff33' in position 1: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: You have a unicode issue, what Python version are you using? and can you post what's in `SINCE` variable

Comment: Can you post what's in `param` and `SINCE` ?

Comment: DAYS = 14                                                                                                                    SINCE = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(DAYS)                                           when print(SINCE),the result is 2016-12-29 00:37:29.296710

Comment: You probably have in `param` some unicode char. whose encoding isn't 'utf-8' because error message says at position 1, can u post what's in `param`?

Comment: what do you mean, what is the "post" in your comment mean

Comment: could you please help me, I have no idea

Comment: Can you post more code?, because like this it is hard for me to keep guessing your issue

Comment: %s is used for epoch timestamps on Linux, %S represents the seconds. So changing from %s to %S is not equal.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody coming here when using ("%s") to generate an Epoch timestamp. Note that the usage of strftime("%s") is platform dependent and doesnt work on windows while it works on Linux with you Local Timezone. You can just use `timestamp()`:

```
int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
```

You can read more here [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Answer (score 0):

> **ValueError: Invalid format string**

You're using the wrong formatter i.e. it has to be upper case 'S'  - here's datetime's [`strftime` reference](http://strftime.org/).

---

> **UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\uff33' in
>   position 1: Illegal byte sequence**

the \uff33 is basically the the [full width latin letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff33/index.htm) 'S' - the one you edited to get rid of previous `ValueError`.

**Solution/way-outs**:

1.[Use raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file) i.e. prefix your string with an 'r'

```
params = r"?fields=permalink_url,from,story,type,message,link,created_time,updated_time,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)"
```

2.If you're using `str()` to convert from unicode to encoded text / bytes - instead use  [`.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode the string. [A helpful SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20).