# Converting date string with timezone to epoch

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert this date string including timezone to epoch time.
(python 2.7)

> Mon, 08 Jun 2009 19:37:51 GMT

I tried to do so like that:

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("Mon, 08 Jun 2009 19:37:51 GMT").strftime('%s')
```

The error I get is:

> ValueError: Invalid format string

What is the problem? How can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce your sample with no issues. I'm on Python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 2):

`Python 3.5` solution using `timestamp()` method:

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse("Mon, 08 Jun 2009 19:37:51 GMT").timestamp())
```

which yields:

```
1244489871.0
```

There are suggestions for not using `strftime`

References:

1. [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)
2. https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#parse-examples