# Convert a set datetime to epoch time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, epoch

Need to convert the time 00:00:00 of each day to epoch time, below is the code I have:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
today_morning = today.strftime('%y%m%d') + "000000"
epoch = int(today_morning.strftime('%s'))
print(epoch)
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

If anyone has any advice, please share it. I have looked around at other answers, but they seem to be for Python 2.X and for the current time, not a predetermined time. I am looking for Python 3.X answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Comment: That's for python 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
today_morning = today.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
epoch = int(today_morning.timestamp())

print(epoch)
```

Comment: Works, but two zeros too short, can add them on though, thank you! :)

Comment: Also have to remove the '.'

Comment: I updated my post to convert the result into `ìnt`, to avoid the final `.0` printed. It gives the results in seconds. If you need the result in ms, you just have to multiply by 1000.

Comment: Did the same :) Cheers though!