# Transform datetime to timestamp python

Tags: python-3.x, time, datestamp

I need your help. 
I have parsed a web site, and I have harvested this:

```
2018-08-18T23:31:00
```

I searched, but couldn't find how to change datetime to timestamp

Example of my desired result :

```
1535414693077
```

Comment: Convert to `datetime` (e.g. `datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)` py3.7 or use `strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`) and call `datetime.timestamp()`

Comment: Ty its work     my_string = "2018-08-18T23:31:00"
    a = datetime.strptime(my_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    b = datetime.timestamp(a)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is incorrect as there is no '%s' formatter in datetime, even though it works, sometimes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743262/2473022) for how wrong it is to use '%s'.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
pytz.utc.localize(datetime.strptime('2018-08-18T23:31:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')).timestamp()
```

Output (float): 1534635060.0