# How to convert Zulu time to Epoch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a timestamp in a file as:
`2019-07-09T16:33:45Z`

How to convert it to epoch time in Python 3?

Eventually I want to compare that Zulu timestamp with a current EST time (if is older than current time or not).

Comment: Possible partial duplicate of [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Possible partial duplicate of [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11743019/4518341)

Comment: The *epoch* timestamp is `0`.  You mean you want a Unix timestamp - that is, a timestamp that is *based* on the Unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).  https://codeofmatt.com/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/

Comment: Correct. But at the end of day - all I want is to compare that Zulu timestamp with current timestamp on my machine..

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [**`time.strptime()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse your date string.
2. If you're working with local times, use [**`time.mktime()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime) to get the Unix timestamp in your timezone. Or use [**`calendar.timegm()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) if you're working with UTC times.

Example:

```
import time
import calendar

timestamp = time.strptime("2019-07-09T16:33:45Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
unix_time_local = time.mktime(timestamp)
unix_time_utc = calendar.timegm(timestamp)
```

Comment: So this unix_timestamp should be epoch time from UTC? Then to see current time - I can use maybe `int(time.time())` and compare the 2?

Comment: @Joe If your datetime is in UTC, you should use [`calendar.timegm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) instead of `time.mktime()`. As suggested [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

Comment: My datetime is EST. Should I convert to UTC in order to compare?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Zulu time but the internet suggests that it's the same as UTC.

There are other date/time libraries (`arrow` is a popular one recently) but in python3 this can be done using the builtin `datetime` using two functions: [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)  and [timestamp](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Here's a quick example solution:

```
import datetime
time_string = "2019-07-09T16:33:45Z"
parsed_datetime = datetime.strptime(time_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
unixtime = parsed_datetime.timestamp()
```

Note that `datetime.timestamp()` returns a float.

Also might be worth noting that for comparison, converting from datetime object to unixtime isn't even necessary - you can simply compare two datetime objects directly like `dt1 < dt2`.

Comment: Yes, Zulu time is UTC. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones