# Convert json field to datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime-format

I get time data from API response like `'2020-02-25T20:53:06.706401+07:00'`. Now I want to convert to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s` format. But I do not know exactly standard format of that time data.

Help me find the time format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to a datetime object and then optionally recreate the string in a new format as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = "2020-02-25T20:53:06.706401+07:00"
dt = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
# Note the capital S
new = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However the `new` value here has lost the timezone offset information. I assume that's OK for you. I also used `%S` instead of `%s` since I assume that's really what you want. The lowercase `%s` wouldn't really make sense, and is also [not truly supported by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743262/10682164).

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat):

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.fromisoformat("2020-02-25T20:53:06.706401+07:00")
print(datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"))
```

Prints

```
2020-02-25 20:53:1582656786
```

Other options:

- Use the third party [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) library
- Use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) which parses the string according to format