# How to change the field of username to user_name in to django custom user model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract-class, django-users

I have created custom user model. now I want to use `user_name` as username field instead of `username`. like shown in below code snippet.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    user_name = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 100 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_name'
```

i'm unable to do that. i'm getting below error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E033) The value of 'ordering[0]' refers to 'username', which is not an attribute of 'accounts.CustomUser'.
<class 'accounts.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'username', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'CustomUserAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

the reason of using this, is because all the project's database tables convention is like this. It would be more better if i could define field name is database just as we do for tables in Meta class like below. where i'm calling my customuser model as user model in db.

```
class Meta:
        db_table = "user"
```

is there anyway to call table field like this way ?

```
class Meta:
            db_table_user_name = "username"
```

if it possible then we dont need to change `username` to `user_name`. we can directly call username field is equal to user_name in database. if and only if it is possible with django models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in admin.py where you are registering your User model. you are registering it with ModelAdmin and in that ModelAdmion you have named field incorrectly. change it to user_name their too.

Comment: brother can i change the label of field in database so that models field still stays username but i label it to user_name for database?

Comment: you can user verbose_name argument if that's what you are looking for 

name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nom")

Comment: brother one more thing.. as you can see it my abstractbaseuser class. Now i'm getting last login field but i dont want that.. How can i remove that ?

Comment: remove last login field from CustomUserAdmin in admin.py

Comment: i didn't use that in admin `class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )

    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('username', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)`

Comment: you want it completely removed or you just dont want to show it in admin panel?

Comment: I want to completely remove it

Comment: django's AbstractBaseUser has last_login field by default. you can create your own AbstractBaseUser class and inherit your model with that instead of django's AbstractBaseUser. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70518925/12009358

Comment: can i override it and change into null and blank true ?

Comment: yeah you can do that too

Comment: you're welcome brother. remember changing into null will not remove that field completely. it'll be there but will have null values

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you don't need to change the field name, just simply override the `username` field with the `db_column='user_name'` parameter and argument:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        db_column='user_name'  # <------------------------
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

[Django doc refrence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column)