# How to convert time to seconds since 1970 wireshark format

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

Hi I have packet time in the format `2022-12-25 13:38:22.561470` and I want to change this to  this format `1671971890.8821542` using python but I don't know how to do it. `2022-12-25 13:38:22.561470` format is store in text file.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and what exactly you're struggling with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert python datetime to epoch with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743019/convert-python-datetime-to-epoch-with-strftime)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime("2022-12-25 13:38:22.561470", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').timestamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module to convert your string to datetime object and then get your timestamp :

```
from datetime import datetime


with open("packet.txt", "r") as f:
    packet_time = f.readline()

print(datetime.strptime(packet_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp())
```

Text file content :

```
2022-12-25 13:38:22.561470
```

Output :

```
1671971902.56147
```