# Sort this list of tuples by the time span

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda, timestamp

```
content_dict = [(u'Bowe Bergdahl', [u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32 EDT']), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", [u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44 EDT'])
```

What is wrong with this lambda function:

```
content2_dict =  sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0],'%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S %z'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amirnakhostin/Documents/Computer Science /Python/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    content2_dict =  sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1],'%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S'))
  File "/Users/amirnakhostin/Documents/Computer Science /Python/test.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    content2_dict =  sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1],'%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'o' does not match format '%a, %d %b %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems with your code.  You improperly formatted `strptime` by omitting the year `%Y`.  You also enclosed the date in a list which caused other problems.  You were trying to use `x[0]` when your date was enclosed in `x[1]`.  Here is a working example of (almost all) of your code (note that the time zone has been removed.  See below for why).

```
>>> content = [(u'Bowe Bergdahl',u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32'), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44')]
>>> content2 = sorted(content, key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%a, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'))
>>> content2
[(u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44'), (u'Bowe Bergdahl', u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32')]
```

However we get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python) that `strptime` has some issues with time zones.  To fix that issue we use the [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32 -0400')
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 16, 3, 32, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

Note that `-0400` is EDT relative to GMT.

To use this to sort your list do something like the following

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> unformatted_content = [(u'Bowe Bergdahl', u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32 -0400'), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44 -0400')]
>>> real_content = [(item[0], parser.parse(item[1])) for item in unformatted_content]
>>> real_content
[(u'Bowe Bergdahl', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 16, 3, 32, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 23, 2, 30, 44, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400)))]
>>> content2 = sorted(real_content, key=lambda x:x[1])
>>> content2
[(u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 23, 2, 30, 44, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))), (u'Bowe Bergdahl', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 31, 16, 3, 32, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400)))]
```

Comment: how do I use the dateutil in a for loop to parse the time stamp?

Comment: using the `parser.parse()` returns a datetime object.  Just sort by the returned object

Comment: @AmirNakhostin I have edited my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: This only works if I have 3 values to parse but the content[] is a list of 200 articles. so is it use a parser in a loop to parse out the time zone and create a new tuple with title and new time?

Comment: thank you I thought i was it but I still get an error. I think it is the format of the original time stamp that causing the issue.

Comment: in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: This is the whole codes:

from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser
import datetime
import feedparser
content = {}
content2= {}
content3= {}
source = ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/", "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss" )
for i in source:
    content = feedparser.parse(i)
    for feed in content.entries:
       content2[feed.title] = [feed.published]
content3 = [(item[0], parser.parse(item[1])) for item in content2]
print content3

Comment: @AmirNakhostin I think that might call for you to ask a new question, that seems like a new issue.  If any answer(s) here have helped you consider upvoting or accepting them.

Comment: absolutely as soon as I can. This was my first question. I am hella newbee in whole programming world. lol   Let me ask 15 questions an I sure will vote you up. Thank you for you help

Comment: @AmirNakhostin You don't need any rep to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer.  It'll actually give you +2 rep yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with a timezone, had to remove it.

```
import datetime

content_dict = [(u'Bowe Bergdahl', [u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32']), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", [u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44'])]

content2_dict =  sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1][0],'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
print content2_dict
```

Comment: how did you remove it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `%Y` between `%b` and `%H:%M:%S`.

To access a time string in your `content_dict`, `x[1][0]` should be used instead of `x[0]`.

Here lies a workaround solution, since python (or datetime module) has some problem handling time zones (HKT can be parsed while EDT can't which confuses me) and assuming that all the timezones are the same, I just simply stripped all the time zones away.

```
content2_dict = sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1][0][:-4], '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems, you are indexing the wrong thing in your lambda, you forgot a year, `%H:%M:%S` can be written as `%X`, and `EDT`, unfortunately, can't be parsed:

```
from datetime import datetime
content_dict = [(u'Bowe Bergdahl', [u'Sat, 31 May 2014 16:03:32']), (u"U.S. 'hypocrisy' in cybertheft charge", [u'Fri, 23 May 2014 02:30:44'])]
content_dict_ = sorted(content_dict, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1][0],'%a, %d %B %Y %X'))
```