# Python dateutil.parser.parse parses month first, not day

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, format, python-dateutil

I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse` to format a date from a string. But now it mixes up the month and the day.

I have a string that contains `05.01.2015`. After

```
dateutil.parser.parse("05.01.2015")
```

it returns:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 1, 0, 0)
```

I hoped the it would return `(2015, 1, 5, 0, 0)`

How can I tell the code that the format is `dd.mm.yyyy`?

For the record, `25.01.2015` will be parsed as `(2015, 1, 25, 0, 0)`, as expected.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Specify `dayfirst=True`:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("05.01.2015", dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 0)
```

This gives precedence to the DD-MM-YYYY format instead of MM-DD-YYYY in cases where the date format is ambiguous (e.g. when the day is 12 or lower). The function is documented [here](https://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Comment: Tnx, this did the job! I have been looking in the documentation you where referring to, but couldn't find anything. But now it's working fine! (I created this code after 12-12-2014, so automatically everything went well.)

Comment: As a warning, note that even with `dayfirst=True` if you pass a "malformed" date such as `01.13.2015`, `parse` will ignore `dayfirst` and interpret `month=1` and `day=13`, which could lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: the way I deal with this is I run all 4 combos of dayfirst and yearfirst and stick the results in a set, if the set has more than one thing in it at the end I raise an "Ambiguous value" error

Comment: Be careful because it also gives precedence to YDM instead of YMD, making it so it fails to correctly parse an ISO 8601 formatted date (`2022-01-06` will be parsed as 1st of June, not 6th of January). There doesn't seem to be a way of making it give preference to DMY over MDY without making it prefer YDM over YMD.

Answer (score 5):

You asked, 'How can I tell the code that the format is dd.mm.yyyy?'

Since you have already imported `dateutil` then most **direct** answer might be to specify the format of the date string but this is quite ugly code:

```
>>> dateutil.parser.datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d.%m.%Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 0)
```

We can see an obvious alternative embedded in the code. You could use that directly.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d.%m.%Y')
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 0, 0)
```

There are also some newer alternative libraries that offer methods and properties aplenty.

Simplest to use in this case would be `arrow`:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.get(date_string, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
<Arrow [2015-01-05T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

Although I find the formatting for [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) easier to remember, [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#installation) uses Python's old formatting system which might save you having to learn arrow's.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> pendulum.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d.%m.%Y')
<Pendulum [2015-01-05T00:00:00+00:00]>
```