# Parsing string into datetime in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

I have a date with this format

```
October 14, 2014 1:35PM PDT
```

I have this in my python script

```
import time

u_date = 'October 14, 2014 1:35PM PDT'

print  time.strptime(u_date,"%b %d, %y %I:%M%p %Z")
```

I got this error as a result

```
ValueError: time data u'October 14, 2014 1:35PM PDT' does not match format '%b %d, %y %I:%M%p %Z'
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening? I'm new to python and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `%Z` can only format timezones, not parse them.

Comment: Plus, you need `%B` for a full month name and `%Y` for a 4-digit year.

Comment: See this topic which is basically trying to do the same thing you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python

Comment: This question seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python

Comment: Martijn Pieters' answer below should help.   For more info on format codes, see here - I thought it was very helpful: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @NJM: parsing a time string with a numeric utc offset (`%z`) is different from a string with timezone abbreviation (`%Z`). The latter may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format is incorrect; `%b` takes an *abbreviated* month, but you have a full month, requiring `%B`, and you have a *full 4-digit year*, so use `%Y`, not `%y`.

The `time` library cannot parse timezones, however, you'll have to drop the `%Z` part here and remove the last characters for this to work at all:

```
>>> time.strptime(u_date[:-4], "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=13, tm_min=35, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=287, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You could use the [`dateutil` library](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead to parse the full string, it'll produce a [`datetime.datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) rather than a time struct:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(u_date)
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 14, 13, 35)
```

Comment: `time.strptime('October 14, 2014 1:35PM PDT', "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p %Z")` works if your local timezone is `America/Los_Angeles`. Otherwise timezone abbreviations such as PDT may be ambiguous and `parser.parse()` may return a wrong result (wrong zone name, wrong utc offset).