# How to convert time to timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, time, timestamp

A time string like this: `'Thu Nov 26 17:49:28 +0000 2015'`.

Need to convert it to UTC timestamp, tried several methods found from online, but not work.

What's the correct way to convert it? Thx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing time string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` with the proper format specifier, and then use the `timestamp()` method:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = 'Thu Nov 26 17:49:28 +0000 2015'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y').timestamp()
1448560168.0
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get "seconds since epoch" from an [rfc 5322 date-time string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3) (like in email `Date` header):

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
>>> mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Thu Nov 26 17:49:28 +0000 2015'))
1448560168
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like Pandas, this is very simple

```
In [32]: import pandas as pd
# Construct date time index
In [33]: dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['Thu Nov 26 17:49:28 +0000 2015'])
# Get the epoch timestamp in seconds
In [35]: dt_index.astype('int64')/1e9
Out[35]: array([  1.44856017e+09])

In [36]: dt_index.astype('int64')[0]/1e9
Out[36]: 1448560168.0
```