# How do you add : to a time formatted like this 203045 in python?

Tags: python, formatting, timestamp

I've been trying to get this time formatted value from 203045 to 20:40:45 in python. I clearly have no clue where to start. Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing time string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strptime` and `strftime` functions from `datetime`, the former constructs a datetime object from string and the latter format datetime object to string with specific format:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("203045", "%H%M%S").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# '20:30:45'
```

Comment: how would you implemented to several values just like 203045 in a row?

Comment: Use `list-comprehension` is not a bad choice. Something like `[datetime.strptime(str1, "%H%M%S").strftime("%H:%M:%S") for str1 in values]`. Replace the `values` here with your actual values.

Answer (score 1):

you can also play with the regular expression to get the same result :)

```
import re
ch = "203045"
print ":".join(re.findall('\d{2}',ch))
# '20:30:45'
```

Comment: that worked but my question now lies as follow. If the number I have is 20304500 and I want this 20:30:45 without the last 2 digits "00" how can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

try this to remove the two last digits if they are equal to zero :

```
import re
ch = "20304500"
print ":".join([e for e in re.findall('\d{2}',ch) if e!="00"])
# '20:30:45'
```

or whatever (the two last digits) :

```
import re
ch = "20304500"
print ":".join(re.findall('\d{2}',ch)[:-1])
# '20:30:45'
```