# Python - Print all log lines that match a pattern between 2 time stamps

Tags: python, regex

Working to print lines that match a specific pattern between a start time and an end time.

Example log line:

> Fri Mar  01 HH:MM:SS YYYY:thresholdcrossed

I am looking for an equivalent of the following:

```
cat /path/file.log | egrep -v "exec|param" | grep thresholdcrossed | sed -n /$start/,/$stop/ >output.file
```

The start and stop will be user generated variables based on the start and stop times they are searching.

This will give me matches for a single line using regular expressions, but I can't get **all** lines that match between 2 time stamps.

```
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search("Mar 10 21.+:.+tstat-threshcrosso", line)  :
        print line
```

Comment: use code indentation in your post

Comment: I'm trying to get it correct.

Comment: When you saw "_but I can't get lines that match between 2 delimiters_", could you elaborate? What are the delimiters you mention?

Comment: I need all lines that match tstat-threshcrosso between a start date/time and stop date/time

There are lots of extra between each threshcrosso over match that doesn't need to be captured.

Comment: Sorry.  I am trying to figure out how to format my existing code

Comment: Are the log lines sorted in time?

Comment: @Suni D S
Yes.  The data looks like this when matching the regex string.
Fri Mar 10 21:51:07 2017:tstat-threshcrosso
Fri Mar 10 21:51:15 2017:tstat-threshcrosso 
Fri Mar 10 21:55:38 2017:tstat-threshcrosso

However between each line wanted there are many more that aren't required

Comment: post the potential values for `$start` and `$stop` variables

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
Fri Mar 10 21:46:07 2017

Answer (score 0):

```
# user defined time range in milliseconds since epoch and
start_ms = 
end_ms = 
# user defined pattern
pattern = "tstat-threshcrosso"

# loop through whole file
for line in hand:
    # strip the line
    line = line.rstrip()

    # parse the line to get time_stamp_ms (ms since epoch) and log_message
    time_stamp_ms = 
    log_message =

    # break if we went beyond end time
    if time_stamp_ms > end:
        break

    # check if the time stamp is within user defined period
    if time_stamp_ms < start_ms:
        continue

    # check for string pattern match
    if pattern in log_message:
        print line
```

You can optimize this by doing a binary search to find the first line after the start time.

Comment: Would the code change if I needed all that matched  
tstat-threshcrosso"  
Between 2 different times  
example:  
Mar 10 21 to Mar 10 23

Comment: @ausrakay define "all"

Comment: Match all lines that contain tstat-threshcrosso between a start and stop times

Comment: This piece of code does find you **all** lines between start and stop that match your pattern.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.  How would I enter milliseconds since epoch?

Comment: https://currentmillis.com/ - be careful with the timezone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python

Comment: Sorry, but I was pulled away from the problem.