# How do I convert string into datetime.datetime object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, python-datetime

I have this date as a string `birthday = "2000-01-23 00:00:00"`

How do I turn it into a `datetime.datetime` object, so when I print `birthday` it prints out `datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 23, 0, 0)`

```
birthday = "2000-01-23 00:00:00"
# birthday = datetime object
print(birthday)
```

Comment: look at the documentation of the `datetime` module in particular at `datetime.strptime()` ( https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strptime ) 

if you want to parse more complicated texts then better look at  `dateutils`, which is not part of the python standard modules, but can be installed with `pip install python-dateutil`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing time string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use strptimelike this

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: i think you meant to say strptime

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third party ***dateutil*** library:

You can install it with:

```
pip install python-dateutil


from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("2000-01-23 00:00:00")  # datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 23, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You can format code by indenting it with four spaces, or selecting it and clicking the button that looks like this: `{}`, not by making it **bold**.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I would do:

```
datetime =datetime.strptime(birthday, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from datetime import datetime

birthday = "2000-01-23 00:00:00"

birthday_object = datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Y-%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Also, I recommend you to take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).