# how to use strtotime to convert time stamp into unixepoch timestamp

Tags: python, date, datetime, unix-timestamp, strtotime

I have a datetime string `2021-10-20 15:42:40+00:00`that I obtain via S3

```
s3_object = s3_resource.Object("testunzipping", "DataPump_10000838.zip")
lastModified = s3_object.last_modified
lastModified = str(lastModified)
```

I need to convert it into a unixepochtimestamp. I was trying this after reading another SO answer

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.strtotime(lastModified)
```

but I get this error:

```
"type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strtotime'"
```

How else can I convert the str or the datetime object into a unixepochtimestamp?

Comment: you are looking for `strptime` not `strtotime`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494312/parsing-time-string-in-python

Comment: try `.timestamp()` method to get the epoch time of a datetime object

Comment: str doesn't have a timestamp() attribute. Is it a function from the datetime module? @GhostOps

Comment: What do I put as the second argument if I use striptime? ```time = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastModified)```

Comment: check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=timestamp#datetime.datetime.timestamp) to know about `.timestamp()` method of datetime object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) (Python 3.7+):

```
import datetime
lastModified = "2021-10-20 15:42:40+00:00"
ts = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(lastModified).timestamp()
print(ts)
# 1634744560.0 # Unix time in seconds
```

Using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
import datetime
lastModified = "2021-10-20 15:42:40+00:00"
ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastModified, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z").timestamp()
print(ts)
# 1634744560.0 # Unix time in seconds
```

**Caveat:** the input here has a UTC offset (+00:00), which, if parsed correctly, will give [aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects). All fine then. If that is not the case (no UTC offset or time zone specified), you'll end up with naive datetime, which Python treats as *local time*. Thus if you call `.timestamp()`, it will be *converted* to UTC first (since Unix time refers to UTC).