# Email datetime parsing with python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse date time of an email using python script.

In mail date value is like below when i am opening mail detils...

```
from:    abcd@xyz.com
to:      def@xyz.com
date:    Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 1:19 PM
subject: Subject of that mail
```

I am using code like

```
mail = email.message_from_string(str1)
#to = re.sub('</br>','',mail["To"])
to = parseaddr(mail.get('To'))[1]
sender = parseaddr(mail.get('From'))[1]
cc_is = parseaddr(mail.get('Cc'))[1]
date = mail["Date"]
print date
```

Where as output of the same mails datetime using python parsing is like below with time offset.

```
Tue, 28 Aug 2012 02:49:13 -0500
```

Where I am Actually hoping for

```
Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 1:19 PM
```

I am so confused between relationship of this two values.
Can anybody help me to figure it out I need to get the same time into mail details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790795/python-parsing-date-with-timezone-from-an-email

Answer (score 26):

When looking at an email in GMail, your local timezone is used when displaying the date and time an email was sent. The "Tue, 28 Aug 2012 02:49:13 -0500" is parsed, then updated to your local timezone, and formatted in a GMail-specific manner.

### Parsing and formatting the stdlib way

The `email.utils` module includes a [`parsedate_tz()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_tz) that specifically deals with email headers with timezone offsets.

It returns a tuple compatible with [`time.struct_time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time), but with a timezone offset added. An additional [`mktime_tz()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.mktime_tz) converts that tuple to an offset value (time in seconds since the UNIX epoch). This value then can be converted to a `datetime.datetime()` type object easily.

The same module also has a [`formatdate()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.formatdate) to convert the UNIX epoch timestamp to a email-compatible date string:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz, formatdate
>>> import time
>>> date = 'Tue, 28 Aug 2012 02:49:13 -0500'
>>> tt = parsedate_tz(date)
>>> timestamp = mktime_tz(tt)
>>> print formatdate(timestamp)
Tue, 28 Aug 2012 07:49:13 -0000
```

Now we have a formatted date in UTC suitable for outgoing emails. To have this printed as my *local* timezone (as determined by my computer) you need to set the `localtime` flag to `True`:

```
>>> print formatdate(timestamp, True)
Tue, 28 Aug 2012 08:49:13 +0100
```

### Parsing and formatting using better tools

Note that things are getting hairy as we try and deal with timezones, and the `formatdate()` function doesn't give you any options to format things a little differently (like GMail does), nor does it let you choose a different timezone to work with.

Enter the external [`python-dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil); it has a parse function that can handle just about anything, and supports timezones properly

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 28, 2, 49, 13, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

The `parse()` function returns a [`datetime.datetime()` instance](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), which makes formatting a lot easier. Now we can use the [`.strftime()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to output this as your email client does:

```
>>> print dt.strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 02:49 AM
```

That's still in the local timezone, of course; to cast this to your timezone instead, use the [`.astimezone()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone), with a new `tzone` object. The `python-dateutil` package has some handy for us.

Here is how you print it in the *local* timezone (to your machine):

```
>>> import dateutil.tz
>>> print dt.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzlocal()).strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 09:49 AM
```

or use a specific timezone instead:

```
>>> print dt.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzstr('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 07:49 AM
```

Comment: Actually I am asking for output of parsed mail which I can capture...like CC,TO or SENDER.....you guided me to format that datetime string...to which I am comfortable enough.

Comment: Right, you are confused about the timezones I think; the email date is parsed as one timezone, displayed in another. This is usually not a problem.

Comment: Note that your question is far from clear; it is not clear where you see the values and what you expected.

Comment: @Martijin : now is it clear?? Actually I am not able to get the string "Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 1:19 PM"..which i can see in my mail when I opens it in my browser in my gmail acc.

Comment: 13:19:21 Tuesday August 28, 2012 in Asia/Kolkata converts to
02:49:21 Tuesday August 28, 2012 in GMT-5...so this is my final answer..thanks @Martijin for your help.

Comment: there are parsedate_tz and mktime_tz i.e., you don't need to parse the UTC offset by hand

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: thanks; not sure how I missed those at the time. It was not as if those functions have been added after I posted this.. :-/

Answer (score 8):

You could do it using only stdlib:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz, formatdate
>>> ts = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Tue, 28 Aug 2012 02:49:13 -0500'))
>>> formatdate(ts, localtime=True) # assuming Asia/Kolkata is the local timezone
'Tue, 28 Aug 2012 13:19:13 +0530'
```

If you want to use `PM` format for hours:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')
'Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 01:19 PM'
```

Comment: J.F. Sebastian is correct just one typo instead of datetime he needs datetime.datetime example should be such  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%a, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p')

Comment: @Dung: the code works as is. Look at the import line.

Comment: In addition, if you want a date format to match mysql datetime format here it is: >>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: @Dung: again, the code works as is. It produces the time format that OP requested *explicitely*. Look at the question.

Answer (score 2):

one could opt for the following code

```
start = f.find('date:') + 5  # +5 is to exclude 'date'+':' i.e.(4+1=5)
end = f.find('subject:', start) # parse from date to subject 
date_time = f[start:end]
print date_time #it will print "Tue, Aug 28, 2012 at 1:19 PM"
```