# How to format pubDate with Python

Tags: python, parsing, date, rss

I am newbie in Python and i m trying to do the following.

In PHP if we want to convert the date we use something like this:

```
$item_date  = date("Y-m-j G:i:s", strtotime($RSSitem->pubDate));
```

Now, i m trying to do the same using Python, but i cant understand the exact method for doing it.

Can anyone help me by writing this line to python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts:

- convert pubDate from string to a datetime/time object. If format for pubDate is fixed you could use `datetime.strptime()` function otherwise you could use [`dateutil.parser.parse()`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil/#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) or [`feeparser._parse_date()`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/) (the later might be easier to install).
- convert datetime/time object to string using `.strftime()` method/`time.strftime()` function.

See [strftime() and strptime() behavior](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: This is the format of pubDate: Tue, 04 Sep 2012 20:20:18 GMT and i m trying to convert it to this: 04/09/2012 20:20

Comment: @zuperakos: read the docs for strptime/strftime functions (see the link above). If you are stuck; update your question with the code that you have tried and its results.

Comment: Great! As i saw, feedparser._parse_date() returns this: time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=4, tm_hour=20, tm_min=20, tm_sec=18, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=248, tm_isdst=0). But how can i get only tm_year, tm_mon, tm_mday, tm_hour and tm_min and create a variable?

Comment: @zuperakos: call time.strftime() on the result to get the string

Comment: @zuperakos: don't put the code in a comment/answer. [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12270531/edit) your question instead.

Answer (score 18):

According to [RSS specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) `pubDate` must follow [RFC822](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html):

```
mytime.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
```

Comment: I had better luck with time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", mytime)

Comment: it is naive. `pubDate` in real rss feeds in the wild can use different time formats. Look at [the source of the `feedparser` module](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/blob/develop/feedparser/datetimes/__init__.py) that is referenced in my answer, to see how many time formats it has to handle. Unrelated: you could [use `email.utils.parsedate_tz/.mktime_tz` to parse rfc822 format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).