# Python: datetime format

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, formatting

I have the following datetime string:

```
Mon Oct 27 23:00:03 +0000 2014
```

I would like to convert this string to a form where I could compare the datetimes. So, the first thing I tried is converting this to a `datetime` in Python.

I am having trouble with the correct formatting. I have followed [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), but it does not work.

I have tried the following:

```
str = 'Mon Oct 27 23:00:03 +0000 2014'
datetime.strptime(str, '%a %b %d %X %Z %Y')
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: related: [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1790795/4279)

Comment: unrelated: don't use `str` as a name. It shadows the Python builtin.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, I know, but it was just an example. In my code, I don't use str as a variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert it to the `datetime` object you can use library [python-dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil).

For example:

```
In [6]: dateutil.parser.parse('Mon Oct 27 23:00:03 +0000 2014')
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 27, 23, 0, 3, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.2+:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> timestr = 'Mon Oct 27 23:00:03 +0000 2014'
>>> datetime.strptime(timestr, '%a %b %d %X %z %Y')
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 27, 23, 0, 3, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Note the lower case %z.

Comment: This returns the following error: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %b %d %X %z %Y'`

Comment: Which Python version are you using? It works for me (Python 3.4.3).

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stdlib-only version that works on Python 2 and 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Mon Oct 27 23:00:03 +0000 2014'))
utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
# -> datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 27, 23, 0, 3)
```

where `utc_dt` is a datetime object that represents time in UTC timezone (regardless of the input timezone).

Note: it doesn't support the time that represents a leap second (though `datetime` object can't represent it anyway):

```
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(mktime_tz(parsedate_tz('Tue June 30 23:59:60 +0000 2015')))
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 1, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with your `%z` UTC offset value (you should've used a lowercase z). However,

> `%z` is only supported in Python 3.2+

If you are stuck with an older version of Python, you could possibly take out the UTC offset from the string and try converting it after you convert the rest