# How can I add exact 'N Minutes' to GMT Time Value & get <ISO8601 Date> in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, iso8601, gmt

I have Date Value as below:

> Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 05:04:47 GMT

I need to add exact '5 Minutes' to above timestamp & get below "ISO8601 Date" value:

> date_time_value =  "2015-03-31T05:09:47.928187755Z"

How can I get this calculation performed in python?

Comment: Parse the value (`datetime.strptime`), add 5 minutes (`timedelta`) and print it out again.

Comment: there are no microseconds in the input time string.

Answer (score 2):

1. Parse the input time string into a datetime object using an answer from [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1790795/4279)
2. `parsed_datetime += timedelta(minutes=5)`
3. Use `datetime.isoformat()` method to get the result `date_time_value` string (for a naive datetime object; add `Z` at the end yourself if you know that the input is in UTC or (better) use an [answer that produces timezone-aware datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279)).