# How to convert string with UTC offset

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have date as

```
In [1]: a = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700"
```

When I try to convert it using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), its giving error.

```
In [3]: datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
   ...: )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-973ef1c6daca> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
      2 )
/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    323     if not found:
    324         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 325                          (data_string, format))
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: time data 'Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
In [6]: datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e4870e34edda> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    315                 del err
    316                 raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" %
--> 317                                     (bad_directive, format))
    318             # IndexError only occurs when the format string is "%"
    319             except IndexError:
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
```

As per doc, correct format is `%z`, but I might missing some part.

Comment: What version of python are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is correct and works fine in Python 3.3:

```
>>> a = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700"
>>> datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 10, 13, 34, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200)))
```

It gives the error in Python 2.7 indeed.

Unlike `strftime()`, which is implemented by calling the libc function, `strptime()` is implemented in the Python library. [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f89216059edf/Lib/_strptime.py#l190) you can see that the version used in Python 2.7 doesn’t support the `z` format. On the other hand [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/91096d27c802/Lib/_strptime.py#l209) is the version from Python 3.3, which supports that (I think this was added around 3.2).

So, basically, you have two options:

1. Using some external library that is able to handle `z`.
2. Implementing it yourself (e.g. by stripping the timezone from the string, feeding the first part to `strptime()` and parsing the second one manually). Looking at how this is done in the Python library might be helpful.

---

I tried to parse this to return an “aware” object, but it is somewhat complicated.

```
>>> a = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700"
>>> time, tz = a.rsplit(' ', 1)
>>> d = datetime.strptime(time, '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 10, 13, 34, 36)
```

Now I have to call `d.replace(tzinfo=…tz…)` to replace the timezone, but the problem is that I can’t get an instance of `tzinfo` because just knowing the offset from UTC is not enough to identify a timezone.

In Python 3.2 there is a special [`timezone`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) class that is a subclass of `tzinfo` representing a “fake” timezone defined by just its offset. So there are two ways to proceed:

1. Backport (basically, copy and paste) the `timezone` class from Python 3 and use it in your parser.
2. Return a “naive” object:

   ```
   >>> d + timedelta(hours=int(tz[1:]) * (1 if tz.startswith('-') else -1))
   datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 17, 34, 36)
   ```

Comment: I am using 2.7, is there any way to parse ?

Comment: @Lafada I’ve updated my answer with some details. I’m afraid you’ll have to parse the timezone part yourself ore use some external library.

Comment: @Lafada I did a little bit of research and added some more details which I hope are helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**From the link you provided for the python doc, I found that you are using Python 2.7**

It looks as if strptime doesn't always support `%z`. Python appears to just call the `C` function, and strptime doesn't support `%z` on your platform.

**Note:** from **Python 3.2 onwards** it will always work.

**I am using Python 3.4**  in which it is working fine

```
>>> a = "Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700"
>>> datetime.strptime(a, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
```

**Update**  using [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil)

```
$ pip install python-dateutil

from dateutil import parser
parsed_date = parser.parse(date)

>>> parsed_date
datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 14, 18, 43, 19)
```

Comment: @Backtrack The `tzinfo=tzutc()` hints that something went wrong: the library returned a “naive” object (the offset was taken into account, though). This might or might not be what @Lafada expects.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your input format using only stdlib even in Python 2.7:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from email.utils import mktime_tz, parsedate_tz
>>> mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Sun 10 May 2015 13:34:36 -0700"))
1431290076
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(_)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 10, 20, 34, 36)
```

The result is a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC.

See other solutions and the way to get an aware datetime object in [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).