# not getting date time from correctly formatted string

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using this code to get the time from lines in a file.

```
    for line in f:
        try:
            dt = parser.parse(line).replace(tzinfo=None)
            print dt
        except Exception, e:
            print line
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            continue


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 90, in read
    dt = parser.parse(line).replace(tzinfo=None)
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

Comment: try with `strip()`: `t = parser.parse(line.strip()).replace(tzinfo=None)`

Comment: instead of just doing `continue` on an exception, how about printing out the traceback so you (and we) can know exactly what's wrong? it's debugging 101

Comment: @Kasra no ... dateutil.parser does not care about extra whitespace

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks i did not knew that!

Comment: unrelated: you could [use `email.utils.parsedate_tz` to parse such time strings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check where you assign `parser` name in your code.

Compare:

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> parser = ArgumentParser()
>>> s = 'Fri May 15 11:22:54 EDT 2015'
>>> parser.parse(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

with:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 15, 11, 22, 54)
```

Answer (score 1):

the best thing you can do is learn to debug your issues with simple print statements

```
for line in f:
    try:
        dt = parser.parse(line).replace(tzinfo=None)\
        print "SUCCESS:",dt
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "UNABLE TO PARSE: %r"%line
        continue
```

now you should quickly be able to find out what the problem is ... clearly the line does not look like your example