# How to parse the date "Thu, 1 Oct 2015 16:05:43 +0200" in python?

Tags: python, time

In python I am trying to parse the date string

```
Thu, 1 Oct 2015 16:05:43 +0200
```

to a `struct_time` trying

```
x = time.strptime(date_string, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000")
```

which yields a `ValueError`.

How to avoid the "+0200" (which I am not interested in)? Just remove the last 6 characters? Or is there a 'better' solution?

Comment: I think you need `%z`.

Comment: The `%z` format string is available on `datetime.strptime` (not in `time.strptime`) and only from Python 3.2 on. For your specific case: you can use `datetime.strptime` + `%z` if you have a recent Python, and then convert it to a `struct_time` via the `datetime.timetuple()` method. But this simple instruction will introduce a dependence towards Python >= 3.2 that perhaps it's not justified by the simple task ...

Comment: use `posix_timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedata_tz("Thu, 1 Oct 2015 16:05:43 +0200"))` from `email.utils`. For pure stdlib Python 2/3 compatible code, see [Python: parsing date with timezone from an email](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last chunk; you can do that by slicing (removing the last 6 characters, yes), or by partitioning (splitting off the last section):

```
x = time.strptime(date_string.rpartition(' ')[0], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Partitioning should continue to work if the last chunk is not 6 characters (say, because you have dates with the timezone expressed as a 3-letter code).

Comment: Instead of partitioning, I'd recommend simply using the proper identifier of `%z` instead of `+0000`.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought I missed some 'special' argument mentioned on the documentation somewhere, but it does not seem to exist. Always trust Martijn...