# Turn a String into a Python Date object

Tags: python, string, parsing, datetime

I have a String, `Sent: Fri Sep 18 00:30:12 2009` that I want to turn into a Python date object.

I know there's a `strptime()` function that can be used like so:

```
>>> dt_str = '9/24/2010 5:03:29 PM'
>>> dt_obj = datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> dt_obj
datetime.datetime(2010, 9, 24, 17, 3, 29)
```

Can anybody think of an easier way to accomplish this than going through a bunch of conditionals to parse out if `Sep, month = 9`?

Answer (score 1):

To parse [rfc 822-like date-time string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.3), you could use `email` stdlib package:

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
>>> parsedate_to_datetime('Fri Sep 18 00:30:12 2009')
datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 18, 0, 30, 12)
```

This is Python 3 code, see [Python 2.6+ compatible code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117071/4279).

You could also provide the explicit format string:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('Fri Sep 18 00:30:12 2009', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 18, 0, 30, 12)
```

See [the table with the format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `python-dateutil` library!

First: `pip install python-dateutil` into your virtual-env if you have one then you can run the following code:

```
from dateutil import parser

s = u'Sent: Fri Sep 18 00:30:12 2009'
date = parser.parse(s.split(':', 1)[-1])
```