# How can I get the RESPONSE time of an email with python?

Tags: python, automation, gmail, imap-tools

How can I get the RESPONSE time of an email with python?
[image]

I tried several ways using the [imap_tools](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools) documentation. But without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract delivery time from an email with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74270428/how-to-extract-delivery-time-from-an-email-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is the date saved by your email client

Not a part of email body

Try to find this dt in .eml